# How can I delete AVG Antivirus on my Xperia Z1?

Tags: uninstallation, delete, antivirus, device-administrator

I have installed AVG Antivirus Free Edition, but when I go to setting to delete it I can't do it, neither the data, only I can delete the cache.

If I go to google play and to AVG Free edition there are 2 options: open and disable. If I select disable appear "This aplications is a administrator of dispositives and you need desactivate it to unistall".

I downloaded 3º app to unistall, but can't unistall it

How can I delete it? Is a non-root device.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to go into `Settings` > `Security` > `Device administrators` and uncheck the box next to the AVG app. You will then be able to uninstall the application normally.

Answer (score 1):

Even if disabled as device admin it may not uninstall - you need to go to avg screen, press the anti theft protected button, then disable/ deactivate, then log out - after that freshly open play store, ie it must not be running in the background, select avg in 'my apps', and you'll see the uninstall button on the avg app details screen.