# How to uninstall AVG which isn't listed under My Apps?

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation, antivirus

That's pretty much it, my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact came with AVG antivirus preinstalled and I can't see how to uninstall it, since it does not show up in Play Store under My Apps / Installed (or anywhere else).
My Android version is 4.4.4 .

Note that my problem is not the one mentioned in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69285/how-can-i-delete-avg-antivirus-on-my-xperia-z1). In my case under `Settings > Security > Device administrators` the checkbox next to AVG was already unchecked.
Instead my problem is simply that I don't know where to start the uninstallation process (and I don't understand why all my installed apps do show up as expected under My Apps but AVG does not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your device AVG is installed as a system application.  To delete this kind of application you have to root your device, then use an app such as Titanium Backup to backup and delete it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to root your device, you should be able to see AVG under the 'All' tab in your list of apps.

If this is the case, open it and there will be one or both of these options available:

1. 'Uninstall Updates' which will reduce the app size and save you space.
2. 'Disable' which will prevent the app from running and will hide it from the app drawer. This will not save you any space as the app will remain on your system.

If you choose to disable it, clearing the data and cache will also save you some extra space.

Comment: Actually having to root my device is a little bit annoying, but my reason for uninstalling AVG is that I want to install another antivirus (Comodo) (yes Sony, I like to decide myself which antivirus I want, thanks). I guess disabling AVG could be enough but I would prefer to actually remove it before installing Comodo.